# Adding new action of GotoLocalPage to exisitng annotation in PDF

Tags: c#, itext

I would like to add a `GotoLocalPage` action using iTextSharp. Unfortunetly, this is not covered in the book `iText in Action - Second Edition` (examples only for Java).

What have I managed to do so far? My annotation had JavaScript code and I removed it by:

```
//remove current JavaScript action
annotAction.Remove(PdfName.S);
annotAction.Remove(PdfName.JAVASCRIPT);
```

I don't know whether this should be done this way but it works fine. Now, when I removed reductant action I want to add a new action to this (already existing) annotation. However, the following code doesn't add the action.

```
PdfAction action = PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(1,
new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, 0, 0, 0.75f), stamper.Writer);
annotAction.Put(PdfName.D,action);
```

**EDIT**

Here's more code of mine:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    // Get a page a PDF page
    PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(i);
    // Get all the annotations of page i
    PdfArray annotsArray = page.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

    // If page does not have annotations
    if (annotsArray == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    // For each annotation
    for (int j = 0; j < annotsArray.Size; ++j)
    {
        // For current annotation
        PdfDictionary curAnnot = annotsArray.GetAsDict(j);

        // check if has JS
        PdfDictionary annotAction = curAnnot.GetAsDict(PdfName.A);
        if (annotAction == null)
        {
            Console.Write("Page {0}, ", i);
            Console.Write("annotation {0}: ", j);
            Console.Write("no action\n");
        }

        // test if it is a JavaScript action
        else if (PdfName.JAVASCRIPT.Equals(annotAction.Get(PdfName.S)))
        {
            PdfObject scriptObject = annotAction.GetDirectObject(PdfName.JS);
            if (scriptObject == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (scriptObject.IsString())
                script = ((PdfString)scriptObject).ToUnicodeString();
            else if (scriptObject.IsStream())
            {
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    ((PdfStream)scriptObject).WriteContent(stream);
                    script = stream.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("malformed JS entry");
                continue;
            }
            if (script.Contains("if (this.hostContainer"))
            {
                //your code here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/D` key is set for Actions to specify the destination. In you particular case, your `action` will have `/D` key with the value of the `PdfDestination` object you are creating.

You, however, are trying to set the action object as the value of the `/D` key, but you should set the destination, i.e.

```
annotAction.Put(PdfName.D, action.get(PdfName.D));
```

However, this would not be enough, because you removed the `/S` key which is a required key for actions and it should be `GoTo` in the case you are trying to achieve. So you would need this line as well:

```
annotAction.Put(PdfName.S, PdfName.GOTO);
```

However, there is a bit simpler and cleaner way to my taste to achieve what you want. You can use your initial `curAnnot` object, from which you got your `annotAction`.  You can just replace the existing JavaScript action with the new one you created with setting `/A` key correctly:

```
PdfAction action = PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(1, new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, 0, 0, 0.75f), stamper.Writer);
curAnnot.Put(PdfName.A, action);
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a million for you answer. I have a question: what does `annot` from `annot.SetAction(action);` refer to? I thought it was `curAnnot` from my `PdfDictionary curAnnot = annotsArray.GetAsDict(j);` but it is not. Please see my updated question for a wider piece of my code.

Comment: I don't see the update to the question, but I assume that `annotAction` is a PdfAction object/dictionary, and I also assume that `annot` is a PdfAnnotation object/dictionary.

Comment: annotsArray.GetAsDict(j) is probably an annotation object. To check which kind of object it is, you should take a look at the `/Type` value

Comment: That's all right, `curAnnot` is an annotation object I was referring to, and the `annotAction` object is indeed an action.

Comment: What makes you think that `curAnnot` is an incorrect object?

Comment: Because the compiler shows an error: `Error CS1061 'PdfDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'SetAction' and no extension method 'SetAction' accepting a first argument of type 'PdfDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. Why?

Comment: I use iTextsharp 5 if it matters.